# Listener for onDraw method

Tags: android, ondraw, android-paint

Following is my onDraw method.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(inte < listOfPoints.size()){
        canvas.drawLine(listOfPoints.get(0).x, listOfPoints.get(0).y, listOfPoints.get(inte).x,listOfPoints.get(inte).y, paint);
        inte++;

        if(inte < listOfPoints.size()){
            invalidate();
        }
    }       
}
```

Is it possible to get a callback once if the canvas has finished drawing the above point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnDraw is automatically called for situations that need to be drawn inside the view, so a Canvas is provided, so it will be called as long as the list size.